# Android Location Manager, Get GPS location ,if no GPS then get to Network Provider location

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am using this given below code to get locations:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,  MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            lat = location.getLatitude();
                            lng = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //get the location by gps
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (mLocationManager != null) {location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                lat = location.getLatitude();
                                lng = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

It is working properly, but I would like to get GPS location first, and in case if it is unavailable , location manager should query for Network provider, in which I am getting trouble.

Please, recommend me the good way to do this.

Comment: Use new locationclient of Play Service. IT IS EASY TO UNDERSTAND.

Comment: this link provide you best way for that 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a?lq=1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're saying that you need GPS location first if its available, but what you did is first you're getting location from network provider and then from GPS. This will get location from Network and GPS as well if both are available. What you can do is, write these cases in **`if..else if`** block. Similar to-

```
if( !isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

// Can't get location by any way

} else {

    if(isGPSEnabled) {

    // get location from GPS

    } else if(isNetworkEnabled) {

    // get location from Network Provider

    }
}
```

So this will fetch location from GPS first (if available), else it will try to fetch location from Network Provider.

**EDIT**:

To make it better, I'll post a snippet. Consider it is in **`try-catch`**:

```
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mCtx
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null, finalLoc = null;

if (gps_enabled)
    gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (network_enabled)
    net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {

    //smaller the number more accurate result will
    if (gps_loc.getAccuracy() > net_loc.getAccuracy()) 
        finalLoc = net_loc;
    else
        finalLoc = gps_loc;

        // I used this just to get an idea (if both avail, its upto you which you want to take as I've taken location with more accuracy)

} else {

    if (gps_loc != null) {
        finalLoc = gps_loc;
    } else if (net_loc != null) {
        finalLoc = net_loc;
    }
}
```

Now you check `finalLoc` for `null`, if not then `return` it.
You can write above code in a function which returns the desired (`finalLoc`) location. I think this might help.

Comment: As much as I know, isGPSEnabled as well as isNetworkEnabled will tell that the providers are enabled or not. But, sometimes there may be the case that even if GPS provider is enabled but we are unable to get the location through that, in that case, it should requery for location updates using the other one, i.e, Network provider. How can that be done?

Comment: please see edit. Let me know if you still need something. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked your edit. The major thing in that, on which I am having doubt is lm.getLastKnownLocation. Is it reliable? What if I have got the last GPS fix 24 hours ago? Will the statement -- "gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);" return 'null' or the location of 24 hours ago?

Comment: Hi I'm sorry for any confusion. I used getLastKnownLocation because its having less number of parameter as compared with requestLocationUpdates. It is just a snippet for reference to give an idea. You can use your own logic to retrieve location.

Comment: well for your question, frankly I've never tried like that. If you've requested for current location, this location (or the latest one) is cached. So if you try next day with getLastKnownLocation, it "might" send you cached fix location.

Comment: .getAccuracy() returns accuracy in meters which means the *larger* the number the *less* accurate, and vice versa. So your logic needs to return gps_loc only if gps accuracy <= network accuracy, else return net_loc

Comment: yes @rockhammer I really wonder how I missed it and no one came across this typo. Thanks for the correction, I commented just above the condition about it so there won't be confusion :)

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to do this is to use `LocationClient`:

First, define location update interval values. Adjust this to your needs.

```
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
```

Have your `Activity` implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, and `LocationListener`.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements 
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {}
```

Then, set up a `LocationClient`in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
}
```

Add the required methods to your `Activity`; `onConnected()` is the method that is called when the `LocationClient`connects. `onLocationChanged()` is where you'll retrieve the most up-to-date location.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Location client connection failed");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location client connected");
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this); 
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location client disconnected");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated Location: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated location NULL");
    } 
}
```

Be sure to connect/disconnect the `LocationClient` so it's only using extra battery when absolutely necessary and so the GPS doesn't run indefinitely. The `LocationClient` must be connected in order to get data from it.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

public void onStop() {
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Get the user's location. First try using the `LocationClient`; if that fails, fall back to the `LocationManager`.

```
public Location getLocation() {
    if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        return mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    } else {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            Location lastKnownLocationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (lastKnownLocationGPS != null) {
                return lastKnownLocationGPS;
            } else {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it is not recommended way. `This class is deprecated.
Use LocationServices.` See https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

Comment: The `LocationManager`,`LocationClient`,and `LocationServices` are very different.`LocationManager` is for getting updates from the Android system.`LocationClient`depends on Google Play Services, is deprecated, and in my experience, is really just bad all around (speed, accuracy, and battery usage). `LocationServices` also relies on Google Play Services and uses a different paradigm for accessing the API. In my experience, it's seems to be a "fixed" version of `LocationClient`(I'd have expected the main change was the methods used to access the services,so maybe external factors were involved).

Comment: The main distinction between the them that I know to apply universally (i.e. isn't based on my experience of them) is that `LocationManager` is the only one of those 3 that _doesn't_ rely on Google Play Services. That means that you can use it on devices without Google Play (< API 8), and you don't have to worry about users having an up to date version of it. At the same time, the two methods based on Google Play Services should be much more "device friendly" (they wrap up location acquisition logic [all the more reason I was surprised by the improved performance I saw with `LocationServices`)

Answer (score 2):

Main Class:

```
public class AndroidLocationActivity extends Activity {

Button btnGPSShowLocation;
Button btnNWShowLocation;

AppLocationService appLocationService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            AndroidLocationActivity.this);

    btnGPSShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGPSShowLocation);
    btnGPSShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile Location (GPS): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                showSettingsAlert("GPS");
            }

        }
    });

    btnNWShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNWShowLocation);
    btnNWShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Location nwLocation = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (nwLocation != null) {
                double latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile Location (NW): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                showSettingsAlert("NETWORK");
            }

        }
    });

}

public void showSettingsAlert(String provider) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AndroidLocationActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle(provider + " SETTINGS");

    alertDialog.setMessage(provider
            + " is not enabled! Want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    AndroidLocationActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

}
```

Next Class:

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

protected LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return location;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Don't forget to add in your manifest.

```
<!-- to get location using GPS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- to get location using NetworkProvider -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I don't think using the network provider requires `INTERNET` permissions. I think it actually needs `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION`.

Answer (score 2):

use the fusion API that google developer have developed with fusion of GPS Sensor,Magnetometer,Accelerometer also using Wifi or cell location to calculate or estimate the location. It is also able to give location updates also inside the building accurately.

```
package com.example.ashis.gpslocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Location sample.
 *
 * Demonstrates use of the Location API to retrieve the last known location for a device.
 * This sample uses Google Play services (GoogleApiClient) but does not need to authenticate a user.
 * See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/tree/master/QuickStart if you are
 * also using APIs that need authentication.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final long ONE_MIN = 500;
    private static final long TWO_MIN = 500;
    private static final long FIVE_MIN = 500;
    private static final long POLLING_FREQ = 1000 * 20;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_FREQ = 1000 * 5;
    private static final float MIN_ACCURACY = 1.0f;
    private static final float MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY = 1;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location mBestReading;
TextView tv;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!servicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(POLLING_FREQ);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_FREQ);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {d
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


        tv.setText(location + "");
        // Determine whether new location is better than current best
        // estimate
        if (null == mBestReading || location.getAccuracy() < mBestReading.getAccuracy()) {
            mBestReading = location;


            if (mBestReading.getAccuracy() < MIN_ACCURACY) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Get first reading. Get additional location updates if necessary
        if (servicesAvailable()) {

            // Get best last location measurement meeting criteria
            mBestReading = bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);

            if (null == mBestReading
                    || mBestReading.getAccuracy() > MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY
                    || mBestReading.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - TWO_MIN) {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

               //Schedule a runnable to unregister location listeners

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, MainActivity.this);

                    }

                }, ONE_MIN, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    private Location bestLastKnownLocation(float minAccuracy, long minTime) {
        Location bestResult = null;
        float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        long bestTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        // Get the best most recent location currently available
        Location mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        //tv.setText(mCurrentLocation+"");
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            float accuracy = mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy();
            long time = mCurrentLocation.getTime();

            if (accuracy < bestAccuracy) {
                bestResult = mCurrentLocation;
                bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                bestTime = time;
            }
        }

        // Return best reading or null
        if (bestAccuracy > minAccuracy || bestTime < minTime) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return bestResult;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private boolean servicesAvailable() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ashis, Good code snippet but after i implemented code snippet some of the mobile devices **(Micromex, Samsung note 4)** gets only loading for almost 30 **[if inside home]** second which is not good.

Comment: @user26174  did you solve the problem or not ?? if not let me know I will give you access to my github.com account and to get the working code .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run inside a background service and take the data in foreground use the below one, it is tested and verified.

```
public class MyService extends Service 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


    private static final int ASHIS = 1234;
    Intent intentForPendingIntent;
    HandlerThread handlerThread;
    Looper looper;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRrequest;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 100;
    private static final int DSIPLACEMENT_UPDATES = 1;
    ;
    private Handler handler1;
    private Runnable runable1;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private float waitingTime;
    private int waiting2min;
    private Location locationOld;
    private double distance;
    private float totalWaiting;
    private float speed;
    private long timeGpsUpdate;
    private long timeOld;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;


    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "speedExceeded";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intentforBroadcast;
    int counter = 0;
    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "binder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        showNotification();
        intentforBroadcast  = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void showNotification() {

        mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                        .setContentTitle("Total Waiting Time")
                        .setContentText(totalWaiting+"");


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, trackingFusion.class);

        // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
        // no need to create an artificial back stack.
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.

        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());


        startForeground(001, mBuilder.getNotification());
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //handler.removeCallbacks(runable);

        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "speed" + speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        timeGpsUpdate = location.getTime();
        float delta = (timeGpsUpdate - timeOld) / 1000;
        if (location.getAccuracy() < 100) {
            speed = location.getSpeed();
            distance += mLastLocation.distanceTo(location);
            Log.e("distance", "onLocationChanged: " + distance);
            //mLastLocation = location;
            //newLocation = mLastLocation;

            Log.e("location:", location + "");


            //speed = (long) (distance / delta);


            locationOld = location;
            mLastLocation = location;

            diaplayViews();
        }

        diaplayViews();
     /*if (map != null) {
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                 .title("Hello world"));


     }*/
    }


    private void createLocationRequest() {

        mLocationRrequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRrequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRrequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRrequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DSIPLACEMENT_UPDATES);

    }


    private void methodToCalculateWaitingTime() {


        if (handler1 != null) {
            handler1.removeCallbacks(runable1);

        }


        Log.e("Here", "here1");
        handler1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        runable1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Log.e("Here", "here2:" + mLastLocation.getSpeed());


                if (mLastLocation != null) {
                    diaplayViews();
                    if ((mLastLocation.getSpeed() == 0.0)) {

                        increaseTime();

                    } else {
                        if (waitingTime <= 120) {
                            waiting2min = 0;

                        }
                    }
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }

                    locationOld = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mLastLocation = locationOld;

                }
            }
        };

        handler1.postDelayed(runable1, 10000);


    }

    private void diaplayViews() {
        float price = (float) (14 + distance * 0.5);

        //textDistance.setText(waitingTime);a
    }


    private void increaseTime() {
        waiting2min = waiting2min + 10;
        if (waiting2min >= 120)

        {
            if (waiting2min == 120) {
                waitingTime = waitingTime + 2 * 60;


            } else {
                waitingTime = waitingTime + 10;
            }


            totalWaiting = waitingTime / 60;
            showNotification();
            Log.e("waiting Time", "increaseTime: " + totalWaiting);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "distroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("Connection_fusion", "connected");

        startLocationUpdates();


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Location location = plotTheInitialMarkerAndGetInitialGps();
        if (location == null) {
            plotTheInitialMarkerAndGetInitialGps();


        } else {

            mLastLocation = location;
            methodToCalculateWaitingTime();
        }
    }

    private Location plotTheInitialMarkerAndGetInitialGps() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return null;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRrequest, this);
        locationOld = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if ((locationOld != null)) {
            mLastLocation = locationOld;

            timeOld = locationOld.getTime();
        } else {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        return mLastLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "start command", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DisplayLoggingInfo();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 5 seconds
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10000); // 1 second
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.e("sent", "sent");
                DisplayLoggingInfo();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // 5 seconds
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");
        intentforBroadcast.putExtra("distance", distance);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentforBroadcast);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in above code to look for a location fix by both GPS and Network for about 5sec and give me the best known location out of it.

```
public class LocationService implements LocationListener {

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    final static long MIN_TIME_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000L;

    Location location;


    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    private CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5 * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            stopUsingGPS();
        }
    };

    public LocationService() {
        super(R.id.gps_service_id);
    }


    public void start() {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

            try {


                timer.start();


                locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Location tempLocation = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (tempLocation != null
                                && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,
                                        location))
                            location = tempLocation;
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Location tempLocation = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (tempLocation != null
                                && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,
                                        location))
                            location = tempLocation;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                onTaskError(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            onOfflineResponse(requestData);
        }
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationService.this);
        }
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        return isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null
                && isBetterLocation(location, this.location)) {

            this.location = location;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResponseObject(Object location) {
        return location;
    }

    public static boolean isBetterLocation(Location location,
            Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location,
        // use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must
            // be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
                .getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
        // accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
                && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

In the above class, I am registering a location listener for both GPS and network, so an `onLocationChanged` call back can be called by either or both of them multiple times and we just compare the new location fix with the one we already have and keep the best one.

Comment: Where is `isSameProvider` in `boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());` declared/defined?

Comment: hi, i'm interested with your code, by the way, why you used timer? and where is onOfflineResponse(requestData) and onTaskError(e.getMessage) function? thanks.

Comment: Instead for looking for GPS location all the time, every time you call start it looks for some time(set in timer). At the end it has the best location found in that time.

Comment: Latest location set in location attribute of this class. This must have been an intermediate code, but you should have a listener with function onLocationFound and call it when in timer finish.

Answer (score -3):

there are better ways to do it as mentioned on android developer sites
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html