# How to get exact longitude and latitude with the influence on those APP that can change user’s longitude and latitude(no network)?

Tags: android, gps

I use LocationManager to get location,but it can be changed by those APP which can change location.

Comment: I think you should put your work to get location that you are talking about. Other wise we don't know how to help you. What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210565/android-locationmanager-get-gps-location-if-no-gps-then-get-network-provider-l):

Here is the code he uses to get GPS with location manager.

To make it better, I'll post a snippet. Consider it is in try-catch:

```
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mCtx
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null, finalLoc = null;

if (gps_enabled)
    gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (network_enabled)
    net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {

    if (gps_loc.getAccuracy() >= net_loc.getAccuracy())
        finalLoc = gps_loc;
    else
        finalLoc = net_loc;

        // I used this just to get an idea (if both avail, its upto you which you want to take as I taken location with more accuracy)

} else {

    if (gps_loc != null) {
        finalLoc = net_loc;
    } else if (net_loc != null) {
        finalLoc = gps_loc;
    }
}
```