# Location from GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER in android is not consistent

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

What I am trying to do

- Get users location at specified interval using a `Service` so that as long as application is running `Location` can be retrieved

Problem I am facing

- Even if I am in same location for long time, each time the `Latitude` , `Longitude` changes with different `Accuracy` levels
- Due to this, even if user has not changed his location, if I am plotting the `Location` in `GoogleMap` it makes jump to very near by places being my zoom level `18.0f`
- `mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLon, 18.0f));`

I have tried approaches mentioned in [stackoverflow Link One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210565/android-locationmanager-get-gps-location-if-no-gps-then-get-network-provider-l/20212677#20212677) and [stackoverflow Link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a?lq=1) 
But even though I am sitting in the same location and retrieving location in regular interval, the Lat and Lon differs like this , **see the highlighted values at end of every lat lon**:

Latitude: 12.8379**283** Long: Longitude: 77.6647**266**

Latitude: 12.8379**233** Long: Longitude: 77.6647**368**

Latitude: 12.8379**285** Long: Longitude: 77.6647**506**

Latitude: 12.8379**245** Long: Longitude: 77.6647**546**

- Now I experimented with this approach [GITHub reference](https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/blob/master/phoneClients/android/app/src/main/java/com/websmithing/gpstracker/LocationService.java)

but still every time the `Accuracy` differs and Lat Lon slightly changes.
 **As my code trials are exactly same as mentioned in link's I am not just copy pasting here.** How can this be resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accuracy of the GPS is not absolute, so even a static device will show different locations in successive readings. Try the following:

1. You can add a method that detects if the mobile is static or not, by reading  he accelerometer - if the delta between two readings is bigger than some threshold - the device is moving. If it's too small - it's not moving. To determine the delta - put the device on a table and see what values you get.
2. Ignore close readings - Take the first reading with good accuracy (<20m or other value you determine) and use it as a reference - if the next reading gives a very small distance, close to the reference (<10m or other value), ignore it. If it's bigger - set it as the new reference.

Answer (score 0):

try to set Accuracy_HIGH and set time limit and distance limits.
try using google places fused api for location related work.
Refer here: -http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

Comment: Last link which I tried is using the same . Anyways thanks for the suggestion.. https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/blob/master/phoneClients/android/app/src/main/java/com/websmithing/gpstracker/LocationService.java

Comment: @Stallion Welcome :) It is requesting location for every 1 sec and there is no distance limit

Comment: I have tried these, locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10, 10, mLocListener); and locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10,10, mLocListener); also, Still the same results I am getting

Comment: @Stallion ok i will try and if found something i will post

Comment: That should be great.Thanks