# How do I get a User's Country Name using their GPS Services?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, country

I'm trying to use a Phone's Location Services to acquire it's current Country.
I've searched over the internet and many cases taught how to get the Long. and Lat. of a phone, but not the country.

To be clear, I'm not trying to get the Phone's Country using:

```
String locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

- I'm not looking for an exact address (City, Street etc.), just the Country.
- I don't need the SIM Card's country (Ex: French user travels to Spain will return France and not Spain)

I've used LocationManager but have no idea how to get Location information from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Geocoder` [getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) which returns and [Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) which has the Country in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's geocoder api to get the full address and then simply extract the country name from it. It's super easy! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html .
This might be overkill for what you want but it certainly does the job

Comment: Lets say I don't have the Lang and Lat, but I do have permission to use the phone's location services. Is there a way to "extract" the country based on that permission? Or must I get the Lang & Lat for that?

Comment: It's really easy to get lat long of device anyway, so you should get lat long and then use the geocoder API. To get lat/long: use LocationManager and then just use the .getLastKnownLocation() method of the location manager. Here is a good resource on using the LocationManager easily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210565/android-location-manager-get-gps-location-if-no-gps-then-get-to-network-provid