# .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) returns always false when gps is off?

Tags: java, android, android-gps

Is it possible to get the location from NETWORK if GPS is OFF ?

My Demo can get the current user-location from NETWORK and from GPS but only if GPS is ON.

If I try to get the location from LastKnownLocation, I get null too.

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
        
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Permissions.class));
            return;
        }
    

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    
    if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
Log.d("TAG", "gps and network false");
           
}else {
if (isGPS) {
loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (loc != null) {
Log.i("TAG", "gps loc found");}
}

if (isNetwork) {
loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (loc != null) {
Log.i("TAG", "network loc found");
}
}
```

I have tested this code below. it returns  the location null too, if I make the device-gps off :
[GPSTracker.java](https://gist.github.com/ashmeh6/dfa95b3a386e78ac36292566298c7839)

Comment: Can you post the code where you retrieve the location? Also, probably similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210565/android-location-manager-get-gps-location-if-no-gps-then-get-to-network-provid

Comment: I have updated the code  to show you how I retrieve the loc.

Comment: I have tested this GPSTracker. it returns null too if gps is off : [GPSTracker.java](https://gist.github.com/ashmeh6/dfa95b3a386e78ac36292566298c7839)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to request the location from the network as a fallback to GPS, you will need to have `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` enabled. Also, even with the permission enabled, you must request a location update, to refresh and update the last network position. Only after that, you'll have the **last known location available**, otherwise, you'll get null indeed.

To make your code work, you probably just need to call your `GPSTracker.getLocation()` before your line with
`getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

You can check the documentation for `getLastKnownLocation` here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

> Gets the last known location from the given provider, or null if there
> is no last known location. The returned location may be quite old in
> some circumstances, so the age of the location should always be
> checked.
>
> **This will never activate sensors to compute a new location, and will**
> **only ever return a cached location.**